# Add an array as a new key value pair in an existing json column in postresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a query
`select * from table`
which will give the data like below

[image: Column_id Column_json Column_array 25 {'a': 1, 'b':2}]

I want to add the column_array into column_json as a new key value like mentioned below
[image]

Any possibilities on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just append it:

```
 column_json || jsonb_build_object('c', column_array)
```

The above assumes that `column_json` is defined with the data type `jsonb`. If that is not the case (which it should), you need to cast it: `column_json::jsonb || ....`